# camera calibration from a set of 2D-3D corresponded points

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have a set of 2D-3D corresponded points and I want to calibrate the camera based on these points. Since the 3D points are not planar, the opencv CameraCalibration function gives me run time error. does anyone knows any solution to solve the problem?

OpenCV Error: Bad argument (For non-planar calibration rigs the initial intrinsic matrix must be specified) in cvCalibrateCamera2, file /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp, line 1592

Thanks

Comment: The easiest answer is: use planar point of a chessboard as shown in the [official documentation of OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html). The function calibratecamera is designed to work after find "planar" corners with findChessboardCorner, as written in the guide. If you don't want to do this, you should be more specific, post yourc ode and specify how your points are generated, so someone could give you a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Then try setting the initial intrinsics. For the focal length (fx,fy), just use (lens focal length in mm) / (image sensor's pixel size in mm). For cx, cy, set the center of the image. If the sensor has 640x480 pixels, set (320, 240). 
You may have trouble finding the image sensor's spec if it's a cheap web cam but if it's an industrial machine vision camera, it should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV calibration requires coplanar points.

If you want to take advantage of 2D - 3D correspondences, you can use DLT camera calibration methods or equivalent methods such as included in the following toolbox : [CalTech Camera Calibration Toolbox](https://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/)

In particular, have a look at [Heikkil](https://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/htmls/example3.html)  where you can calibrate your camera from a non-planar rig.